# malloc.c: No such file or directory

Tags: c, malloc, runtime-error

I am trying to write a program in C which accepts a stream of inputs and break the input based on the occurrence of spaces in the string and creates a 2-D array from them. e.g.

If input is :

`this is cat`

Output:

`this`
`is`
`cat`

My code is as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
int ** a;
int * element;
int i;
int size = 2;
int element_size = 2;
int element_count = 0;
char c;
int flag = 0;

if((a = (int **)calloc(size, sizeof(int **))) == NULL){
    printf("Not enough space");
    exit(0);
}
for(i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    element_size = 2;
    element_count = 0;
    flag = 0;
    if(i >= size){
        size *= 2;
        if((a = (int **)realloc(size, sizeof(int **))) == NULL){
            printf("Not enough space");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    if((element = (int *)calloc(element_size, sizeof(int *))) == NULL){
        printf("Not enough space");
        exit(0);
    }
    while(1){
        c = getchar();
        if(element_count >= element_size){
            element_size *= 2;
            if((element = (int *)realloc(element_size, sizeof(int *))) == NULL);
        }
        if(c == ' '){
            flag = 0;
            break;
        }
        else if(c == '\n' || c == '\0' || c == '\r'){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        else{
            element[element_count] = (char)c;
            element_count++;
        }
    }
    element[element_count] = '\0';
    *a[i] = element;
    if(flag == 1)break;
}
for( i = 0; i < size; i++){
    printf("%s\n", *a[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

This code is giving runtime error `SIGSEV` with coredump.

Analysis of core dump with gdb shows:

`Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. #0  __GI___libc_realloc (oldmem=0x4, bytes=8) at malloc.c:2977
2977    malloc.c: No such file or directory.`

What does this error mean?

It would be very helpful if one can point out error in my code or any new method of do so.

Comment: `a = (int **)calloc(size, sizeof(int **))) == NULL` should be  `a = calloc(size, sizeof(int *))) == NULL`

Comment: @Gopi can you give the reasoning?

Comment: All your `alloc`'s are wrong. If you're allocating an array of X, then you'll be assigning the result of `...alloc` to a variable of type *X, but using sizeof(X) -- NOT sizeof(*X) -- in the allocation. Likewise, **X = ...alloc(...sizeof(*X)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two calls to `realloc` and both of them are wrong. The first argument to `realloc` is the pointer to the memory region to be reallocated, and the second one is the size *in bytes*.

That's completely different from the arguments to `calloc`. Note that `realloc` does not clear the new memory. If you require the additional allocated memory to be cleared, you should clear it yourself. If not, it may be that the `calloc` could be replaced by `malloc`, but that's up to you.

I think your compiler warned you about this. When you compiled, you should have seen a warning like this: (with a different filename, of course)

```
badrealloc.c: In function ‘main’:
badrealloc.c:25:9: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘realloc’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         if((a = (int **)realloc(size, sizeof(int **))) == NULL){
```

Another important warning is triggered at line 58, by the way.

In C, it is not necessary to explicitly cast the return of the alloc functions, and many people (including me) will suggest that you don't do that. Also, it is usually better to use `sizeof` on a value of the desired type, rather than trying to work out the type yourself, which is error prone. (Two of your calls to `realloc` and `calloc` get this wrong, for example).

So I'd suggest:

```
if((a = realloc(a, size * sizeof *a))) == NULL)
```

The above is really not correct, however, since it leads to a memory leak when the realloc fails. What you really should do:

```
{ void* tmp = realloc(a, size * sizeof *a);
  if (tmp) { a = tmp; }
  else {
    free(a); /* Avoid the memory leak */
    /* Handle the error */
  }
}
```

Comment: yes.. arguments of `realloc` and `calloc` and `line 58` and `line 54` is the main issue. Got the output.

Comment: @princethewinner: I fixed the copy and paste error in my answer. (And added the usual warning about memory leaks and realloc.) Sorry if it was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i = 0; i <= size; i++)
```

should be

```
for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

and

```
a = (int **)calloc(size, sizeof(int **)))
```

should be

```
a = calloc(size, sizeof(int *)))
```

With `i<=size` you are accessing out of bound and having undefined behavior.

`int **a` is an integer pointer to pointer and you need to allocate memory to pointer which is `int *`

Answer (score 0):

What sticks out to me is that malloc is included in stdlib.h ; there is no such header as malloc.h. If you remove the header declaration you should be better off.

H@ppy <0d|^g!

Comment: It's not the compiler complaining about malloc.h being missing. It's the debugger complaining about malloc.c being missing; the result is that the debugger cannot show the source code for the line in which the error occurs. By the way, glibc includes a malloc.h header which you use if you need to set malloc options. (See `man mallopt`.) In this case, it is not necessary, of course.

Comment: that's all i was pointing out. he said to mention anything else he was doing "wrong" and noone had pointed this one out yet. and come to think of it, noones pointed out the .c problem you mention here either